# How to define integer lists

Tags: prolog

I have a problem shown below.

Define integer list as follows:

1. the empty list is an integer list
2. if L is an integer list and N is an integer then [N | L] is an integer list
3. if L1 and L2 are integer lists, so is [L1 | L2].

Write a prolog program `integer_list(L)` that is satisfied if only if `L` is an integer list.

My program cannot implement the 3rd requirement. Can someone point out to me the mistake?

```
int_list([]):-!.
int_list(L):-
   is_list(L),
   L=[X|Y],
   check(L).
int_list(L):-
   L=[L1|L2],
   is_list(L1),
   is_list(L2),
   check(L1),
   check(L2).


check([]):-!.
check([X|Y]):-
  integer(X),
  check(Y).
```

Comment: If `L1` and `L2` are lists, then `[L1|L2]` is a compound list in which the head itself is a list. For example, if `L1` is `[1,2]`, and `L2` is `[3,4,5]`, then `[L1|L2]` is `[[1,2],3,4,5]`. Is that what's intended?

Comment: When you want to raise an issue about a requirement not being met by your code, it is best to give an example input that produces an error or an incorrect result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do more simply, extending check to accept lists of integers:

```
int_list([]).
int_list([X|Xs]) :- check(X), int_list(Xs).

check([X|Xs]) :- check(X), int_list(Xs).
check(X) :- integer(X).
```

note: try to avoid cuts when not necessary (i.e. to commit to a specific choice). The code will be easier to understand, and equally efficient, if you let Prolog pattern matching discriminate branches.

Comment: In short user2585677 errs in having the second and third clauses for `int_list/1` rely on auxiliary predicate `check/1` to handle recursion, since that version of `check` only implements rules 1 and 2.  The recursion needs to account for all three rules, which CapelliC manages by having `int_list` and `check` be mutually recursive.

Comment: This predicate is too specific: Since by definition (1) above, `[]` is an integer list, then by definition (3) above, `[[]|[]]` is also an integer list, but `?- int_list([[]|[]])` yields `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
integer_list( X      ) :-   % an unbound variable is NOT an integer list.
  var(X) ,                  %
  ! ,                       %
  fail.                     %
integer_list( []     ) .    % The empty list is an integer list.
integer_list( [X|Xs] ) :-   % A non-empty list is an integer list if:
  integer(X) ,              % - its head is an integer, and
  integer_list(Xs) .        % - its tail is an integer list.
integer_list( [X|Xs] ) :-   % A non-empty list is an integer list if:
  integer_list(X) ,         % - its head is an integer list, and
  integer_list(Xs)          % - its tail is an integer list.
  .                         % Easy!
```

Comment: Nicholas, your code is formatted in unusual and attractive way. Do you use some IDE or do it by hand ?

Comment: I like the approach of using a single (recursive) predicate.

Comment: @CapelliC - by hand. There's a lot of cognitive research that shows that well-formatted code, where stuff is put in tabular form makes form better and easier comprehension. Like Perl, Prolog code can look a lot like line noise if you're not careful B^) And I find, for SO especially, where the audience for Prolog is usually a novice/students, having a column of line-by-line comments in the example code, explaining what the code is doing helps them better comprehend it. As a writing teacher of mine said, you have to know your intended audience and write for them.

Comment: Your first clause has an unfortunate effect: The must general query `?- integer_list(X).` yields `false`, but we know that there are integer lists, for example `[]`. This renders your predicate non-monotonic: `?- X = [], integer_list(X).` succeeds, but the declaratively equivalent query `?- integer_list(X), X = []` fails. It is true that an unbound variable is *not* an integer list, but it would be really nice to get actual solutions that *are* integer lists from the most general query.

Comment: Making it generative raises the level of complexity. For starters, `integer/1` doesn't generate integers: it just checks whether or not the term passed it is an integer. To make it properly generative, you'll need to roll your own `integer/1` that behaves in the needed way, generating the [very large] set of integers sequentially on backtracking.

Comment: Simply use finite domain constraints to constrain variables to integers. For example, with SICStus, YAP and SWI's `library(clpfd)`: the constraint `X in inf..sup` makes sure that `X` is an integer even without enumeration. But even with `integer/1`, raising an instantiation error is much preferable to silently failing even though there are solutions, so it would in my opinion already be an improvement to simply remove the first clause, and then to use constraints to make it a pure relation.